# Using only Scribble for WatchKit Text Input

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos-3

I'm currently working on a watchOS 3 Complication and wish to take the user  directly to the Scribble Input mode. Is there a way to configure the presentInputControllerWithSuggestions method to do so?

For dictation only input, there's a simple solution to use nil in the suggestions parameter, but there don't seem to be any way to allow Scribble only input.